# Merge statement not working. SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values

Tags: sql, oracle

I run this in RazorSQL:

```
MERGE INTO GMA_THRESHOLDS USING dual ON ( "CIRCLE_ID"=12 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET "MIN_DURATION_OC"=16 , "MAX_NUMBER_IC"=17
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ("CIRCLE_ID","TSP_ID","MIN_NUMBER_OC","MAX_NUMBER_IC","MAX_DURATION_IC","MAX_NUMBER_CELL_ID","DISTINCT_BNUMBER_RATIO","MIN_PERCENT_DISTINCT_BNUMBER","FLAG") 
VALUES ( 10,23,4,6,7,6,3,"12",12,"1" );
```

It's giving an error too many values.

I don't know how to approach it. Please help.

Comment: Count the number of columns in the insert statement. Then count the number if values you're inserting.

Comment: Do you really have a column name `12`? Because `"12"` is a column name, not a value. You either need to write `12` if it's a number or `'12'` if it's a character column.

Comment: @Mat: You were right. I had one number of columns mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to insert 10 values into 9 columns. Hence, "too many values".